# Can I NAT a public ip that is also used as a VPN peer

Tags: cisco-asa

I have been reading books and sites on the web for two days and have tried all kinds of things to be able to ping a IP address further into my private network.

The VPN tunnel is up and passing other data just fine.

The IP I am trying to reach is 10.106.70.10.

My setup is a remote site with 5505ASA v8.2(5), public IP 71.43.109.226
going to main site 5540ASA v8.4(3).

The ping makes it from remote site 5505 to main site 5540 and shows receive data but no transmit data.  It shows up at the main site 5540 with source IP 71.43.106.226.
Also I can ping the IP 10.1.0.125 from the remote site, but this device is on a 6509 that is directly connected to the 5540.

The problem is when it gets to the 10.106.70.10, since we do not route public IP's inside the network it takes the first default route it finds and goes back to the internet instead of back to the main site 5540.

I was trying to NAT the public 71.43.106.226 to a private IP 10.1.0.200 at the main site 5540.
But it just isn't working.  I have tried the following commands so far and all kinds of other commands.

```
nat (outside,inside) source static CitySouthPIX CitySouthPIX destination static CitySouthPIX-In CitySouthPIX-In
nat (inside,outside) source static CitySouthPIX-In CitySouthPIX-In destination static CitySouthPIX CitySouthPIX
nat (outside,inside) source static CitySouthPIX CitySouthPIX destination static CitySouthPIX-In CitySouthPIX-In

object network CitySouthPIX-In
 host 10.1.0.200
 description City South PIX Inside NAT

object network CitySouthPIX
 host 71.43.109.226
 description City South PIX
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment (not enough points), so I will answer. I could be wrong, it's been way too long since I've configured ASA's with P2P VPN's...

Don't you need a

```
access-list nonat extended permit ip -localIP- -localSubnet- -remoteIP- -remoteSubnet-
```

statement?

Comment: Tried that already. when I do that I can no longer get to my remote 5505.

Comment: I will try the nonat, haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Create some static routes to the outside networks on the border router and redistribute them into your local network.